# Hosting Ruby on Rails 000webhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ftp

I am trying to host my website onto 000webhost with my rails app. In Filezilla(ftp client) I added the folder where my rails app is but it says it needs to have an index file in order to display. I have an index file inside my welcome controller folder, but how do I get my host website to access this. Anyone with experience on doing this and pointing me in the right direction would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, the host does not support Ruby, only PHP. To run your code Rails project find a host that has Ruby language support. Example: Heroku.

Comment: Ah yes, this is what I decided to use now I have a functioning app